# Compute the characteristic equation 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone help me explain how to solve this problem below:

> Let the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ be given as $$\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1&-1\\1&2&1\\1&1&2\end{bmatrix}$$
>   1.  Compute the characteristic equation.

Would something like this be correct?

$$(\lambda-2)(\lambda-2)(\lambda-0)-\ldots$$

But I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Do it like in [this MSE-question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88324/how-to-compute-the-characteristic-polynomial-of-a).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easy and quick way to compute the characteristic equation of 3x3 matrix is to use the formulae 
$$x^3-tr(A)x^2+(A_{11}+A_{22}+A_{33})x-det(A)=0$$
For given matrix $$tr(A)=4, A_{11}(cofa_{11})=3, A_{22}(cofa_{22})=1, A_{33}(cofa_{33})=1, det(A)=2$$
so the char equation will be
$x^3-4x^2+5x-2=0$

Comment: Your formula is incorrect: $A_{11} + A_{22} + A_{33}$ is the same thing as the trace, which is not the linear coefficient.  The correct formula is given [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CharacteristicPolynomial.html).

Comment: Sir these are cofactors of diogonal elements not the elements of matrix

Comment: I'm inertsting in what do compute to get the result A11 = 3?

Comment: Oh, my mistake.  You should probably change your notation:  for a matrix $A$, $A_{ij}$ typically denotes the $i,j$ entry.

Comment: For elements of matrix we use small alphabets/

Comment: In any case, I think it is a good idea to include what the $A_{ij}$ denote in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Quick way:** Note that sum of each column of $A$ is $2$, hence $\lambda_1=2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.Let $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ be other eigenvalues,using trace and determinant $\lambda_1 +\lambda_2=2$ and $\lambda_1 \lambda_2=1$,hence $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1$
Hence Characteristic polynomial $p(x)$ is $$p(x)=(x-1)^2(x-2)$$

Comment: But you don't show how to compute the characteristic equation?

Comment: @AdiT Once you know your the eigenvalues, you know the factorization of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this method? I've never heard of any result that relates the sum of the columns to an eigenvalue.  For the rest, I think I follow your reasoning for the trace ($2 + \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 4 \; \Leftrightarrow \; \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 2$), but I don't see how you identified the determinant without computation. Most curious about the "sum of each column" part, though.

Comment: @RaxAdaam: Consider transpose of the matrix and multiply this transposed matrix with the vector $(1,1,1,...1)$. Finally recall that $A$ and $A^T$ have same eigenvalues

Answer (score 2):

The **characteristic equation** is used to find the eigenvalues of a square matrix *A*.

*First:* Know that an eigenvector of some square matrix *A* is a non-zero vector *x* such that ***Ax = λx***.

*Second:* Through standard mathematical operations we can go from this: ***Ax = λx***, to this: ***(A - λI)x = 0***

The solutions to the equation **det(*A - λI*) = 0** will yield your **eigenvalues**.
The previously mentioned equation *is the characteristic equation.*

**-- SKIP TO THIS POINT FOR THE SHORT ANSWER --**

Given some square matrix *A*, the characteristic equation is **det(*A - λI*) = 0**.

***Example:***

$$  A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$$$  λI = \begin{bmatrix}
    λ & 0 \\
    0 & λ \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

$$  A - λI = \begin{bmatrix}
    a-λ & b \\
    c & d-λ \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

$$det\begin{bmatrix}
    a-λ & b \\
    c & d-λ \\
    \end{bmatrix} = 0$$ **Characteristic Equation:** $$(a-λ)(d-λ) - (c)(b) = 0$$

Source Cited: Lay, David C., et al. Linear Algebra and Its Applications, Fifth Edition. Pearson, 2016.

Answer (score 0):

That is incorrect. The characteristic equation comes from computing the $\lambda$ values necessary to give you a matrix determinant equal to zero.

$$\begin{vmatrix}
-\lambda & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 - \lambda & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 2- \lambda
\end{vmatrix} = 0
$$

Notice that for $\lambda = 1$ all three columns become identical and we can come up with two eigenvectors. Coming up with the last eigenvalue should be easy if we use the fact that the trace of the matrix is the sum of the eigenvalues.

The eigenvalues for this matrix are thus $\lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2 = 1, \lambda_3 = 2$ as they make the matrix singular.