# Find the eigenvalues of a matrix in a special case (using cofactors - diagonal)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix $A_{(3x3)}$ with determinant iqual to zero, null trace and their cofactors of the diaganal such that $\Delta_{11}=-1$, $\Delta_{22}=0$, $\Delta_{33}=-1$. Some TIPS to calculate the eigenvalues of the $A$ matrix?

Comment: check this out: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1721776/97188

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characteristic equation will be
$$x^3-2x=0.$$
The $-2$ is $\Delta_{11}+\Delta_{22}+\Delta_{33}$.

Comment: What is the relation of the determinat of the $A-\lambda I$ and the trace and the cofactor of the matrix $A$?

Comment: The trace and determinant of a matrix are up to sign the $x^{n-1}$ and constant terms of its characteristic polynomial.