# Why is the second coefficient of the characteristic polynomial for a 3x3 matrix the sum of cofactors?

Tags: linear-algebra

In another post here someone mentioned that the second coefficient of the characteristic polynomial is the sum of cofactors. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1721776/665392

Can you give me an intuition for why that would be the case?