# Spectral mapping theorem calculations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Can someone help me solving this problem? I did some calculations and I know that A is diagonasable by $D=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 &  0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $, such that $A = X^{-1}.D.X$  But I am not sure if I can use that property or if that has something with the spectral mapping theorem?
>
> C shoud be the zero matix.
>
> Let $A:=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 2 \\
> 0 &  2 & 0 \\-1 & 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix} $
>
> And let $C:= A^3 -3.A^2 +2.A$. Show that $C=0$.

Comment: The eigenvalues of $D$ (and hence of $A$) are the diagonal elements.  Therefore the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $(x-2)x(x-1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Compute the characteristic equation 3x3 matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1721765/compute-the-characteristic-equation-3x3-matrix) or by direct computation we know that the characteristic polynomial of $D$ (and hence of $A$) is
$$f(\lambda)=\lambda^3-3\lambda^2+2\lambda+0$$
But by [Cayley Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem)
$$f(A)=0$$
hence $$A^3-3A^2+2A=:C=0$$

Comment: Is it there maybe another way solving that problem without using Cayley Hamilton Theorem? As that is a homework question  and we have not lerned about this Theorem at all ....

Comment: Yes. Writing $A=SDS^{-1}$, we have that $C$ is just $S(D^3-3D^2+2D)S^{-1}.$ Now show (by direct computation that
$$D^3-3D^2+2D=0,$$
which is very easy to compute since $D$ is diagonal

Comment: Thank you very much !