# Given the characteristic equation, how to find the determinant of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

Take a look at this question:

Find $\det(A)$ given that A has $p(\lambda)$ as its characteristic polynomial.
$$
p(\lambda) = \lambda^3 - 2\lambda^2 + \lambda + 5
$$

My first step is to notice the following:
$$
\det(\lambda I -A) = \lambda^3 - 2\lambda^2 + \lambda + 5
$$
But $\det(\lambda I-A) \neq \det(\lambda I) - \det(A)$. Any idea or hint to what to do with the aforementioned equation to compute $\det(A)$? Do I have to compute the eigenvalues and substitute them?

Comment: try to set $\lambda =0$

Comment: Hint: what is the constant term in $p(\lambda)$?

Comment: @Thomas, would you please explain why is that?

Comment: The constant term of $p(\lambda)$ is the product of the roots of $p$, with a sign convention, according to Vieta's Formula.

Comment: Oh please. Just set $\lambda = 0$ in your equation and check what it reads.

Comment: @Thomas, it tells me $\det(A) = -5$ but why?

Comment: Close, but no. It tells you $det (-A) = 5$ That's a difference.

Comment: @Thomas, true but we can take out the minus out according to $\det(kA)=k^n \det(A)$ but I'm confused why you set the eigenvalue to zero.

Comment: yes, but the sign depends on the dimension. -- your question was how to find the determinant of a matrix. That equation tells you its value, so your question should be answered. As for the why: i) it is an equation valid for each complex number $ \lambda $, so esp. it is true for $\lambda =0$ ii) read the other comments.

Comment: @Thomas but the dimension is the order of the characteristic equation, right? In this case $n=3$. Could you please suggest a reference or wiki page for why $\lambda=0$ is valid? I'm still confused. I feel there is something I should know a priori.

Comment: If $p(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I - A)$, then $p(0) = \det(-A)$, no?

Comment: Alternatively: thinking about the Jordan canonical form, it should be clear that the determinant of $A$ is the product of all its eigenvalues, counting multiplicity. And the eigenvalues are precisely the roots of the characteristic polynomial. And in any polynomial, the product of its roots is (plus or minus) the constant term.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but check the first answer on this, it might help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1721765/compute-the-characteristic-equation-3x3-matrix

Comment: $\det|A|=-5$, see my Answer below. Also, for example $I^3-I=0 \implies \det|I|=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of algebra, we see that
\begin{align}
p(\lambda) = (\lambda-z_1)(\lambda-z_2)(\lambda-z_3)
\end{align}
where $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are the roots which means
\begin{align}
p(0) = (-1)^3z_1z_2z_3 = -\det(A).
\end{align}

Comment: Nice answer and lucid.

Answer (score 0):

$ \det(-A)=p(0)=5.$ Can you proceed ?

Answer (score -1):

By Caley-Hamilton theorem a matrix satisfies its own charateristic equation so Here we have
$$A^3-2A^2+A+5I=0~~~~(1)$$
A $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ satisfies a unique monic cubic:
$$A^3-Tarce(A)~ A^2+Trace(adj~ A)~ A-\det|A| I ~~~~(2)$$ By comparision
of (1) with (2), we get $\det|A|=-5.$

Also, for example $I^3-I=0 \implies \det|I|=1$